# How to use EM_CHARFROMPOS with TMemo?

Tags: delphi

In a TMemo, I want to obtain the character index of the character next to the (blinking) caret.
I have tried something like this bot doesn't work:

```
function TMyMemo.CursorToChar: Integer;      
VAR  Pt: TPoint;
begin
 Pt := CaretPos;
 Result:= Perform(EM_CHARFROMPOS, 0, MakeLong(pt.x, pt.Y));
end;
```

Comment: Ups. It looks like EM_CHARFROMPOS returns the position of the character under CURSOR not CARET! Which is the EM_ message then, for what I want?

Comment: It is not related to neither the cursor nor the caret. You pass the coordinates that you want the index of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The low order word of the result of the message specifies the character index of the passed position. Additionally do not use `CaretPos` of `TMemo`, it returns a coordinate in characters.

```
function TMyMemo.CursorToChar: Integer;
VAR  Pt: TPoint;
begin
 windows.GetCaretPos(Pt);
 Result:= LoWord(Perform(EM_CHARFROMPOS, 0, MakeLong(Pt.x, Pt.Y)));
end;
```